# opensource DMS with API for Java EE application access

Tags: jakarta-ee, jackrabbit, document-management, modeshape, openkm

We have a Java EE application clustered with load balancer and we are looking to store some documents (mostly PDF and MS Word). For this, we need to setup a simple and basic Document Management System (DMS) which is Opensource and free.

We should be able to upload the documents to the DMS via our application and retrieve the documents from the DMS and display it or display a link through our application UI. We are not planning to use the UI provided by the DMS. We should be able to interact with the DMS via API.

I looked into OpenKM and tinyDMS but not sure if I can interact via some Java API.
Could you please let me know some suggestions on the DMS with which we could interact via Java/ Java EE for storing and retrieving the documents (mainly PDFs few KBs upto 50MB).

Comment: 1) This question actually does not belong to SO. 2) Are you sure you need a DMS, if you don't plan to use its UI? Wouldn't be a [JCR API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java) implementation such as [Jackrabbit](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/index.html) or [ModeShape](http://modeshape.jboss.org/) enough?

Comment: I am kind of new to this area. Could you give me some more information on this? Can the document be stored and retrieved in jackrabbit and Modeshape? You mean jackrabbit oak? Do these have their own storage or datastore? I kind of looked into these two but not quiet sure if these are just API implementations or they have some datastore

Comment: Start with [this](http://www.slideshare.net/cziegeler/jcr-in-action-apachecon-us-2009) or [this](http://www.slideshare.net/jchochol/jcr-and-modeshape) presentation, study. In general, any content can be stored in JCR, you have to implement this (well, there might be some utilities to help you). I am not sure what do you mean by datastore - you have to define how the data are stored, JR supports JPA (database), ModeShape has more options.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. Can jackrabbit or modeshape be setup as a separate server and accessed via the API? Our application is clustered with a load-balancer and we need to be able to store/ retrieve the documents from all the application servers in the cluster

Comment: Yes, at least ModeShape is well integrated with JBoss/WildFly AS. Jackrabbit probably too, but there I have no experience.

Comment: I looked into these and Modeshape doc. Could you please clarify the following per my application (clustered JEE app on jBoss 4.0.x): 
1. I need to deploy Modeshape to a web server (jboss 6.1 atleast). Correct?
2. Need to add binary store location for storing files in filesystem. Any difference between Standard and Composite binary stores?
3. Inifispan cache is used only for properties/ metadata and the Binary store location is used to persist files. Correct?
4. Is infinispan cache persistent after restart or should these properties and metadata be saved elsewhere?